# Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Set

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

During migration on Spring Boot 3 I increase Hibernate version to 6.3.1 final. When I try to start application or run unit tests I got

```
Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Set r.s.c.repository.LoadProfileRepository.findLoadProfileOutcomeIdsByStructureId(java.util.UUID); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Set r.s.c.repository.LoadProfileRepository.findLoadProfileOutcomeIdsByStructureId(java.util.UUID)
```

```
Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.util.UUID' with right expression of type 'r.s.c.model.metric.LoadProfile
```

My repository method

```
@Query("SELECT lp.loadProfileId FROM LoadProfile lp JOIN ProfileInteraction pi ON lp.loadProfileId = pi.outcome WHERE lp.structureId = ?1")
    Set<UUID> findLoadProfileOutcomeIdsByStructureId(@Param("structureId") UUID structureId);
```

My Entity

```
public class LoadProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "load_profile_id")
    private UUID loadProfileId;
    @Column(name = "structure_id")
    private UUID structureId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "load_profile_id")
    private List<MetricInProfile> metrics;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        LoadProfile that = (LoadProfile) o;
        return Objects.equals(structureId, that.structureId) && Objects.equals(name, that.name) && Objects.equals(metrics, that.metrics);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(loadProfileId, structureId, name);
    }

    public void addMetric(MetricInProfile metricInProfile) {
        metrics = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(metrics, ArrayList::new);
        metrics.add(metricInProfile);
    }
}
```

ProfileInteraction

```
public class ProfileInteraction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "income", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LoadProfile income;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "outcome", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LoadProfile outcome;
}
```

Tried to refactor my method like this

```
@Query("SELECT lp FROM LoadProfile lp JOIN ProfileInteraction pi ON lp.loadProfileId = pi.outcome WHERE lp.structureId = ?1")
    Set<LoadProfile> findLoadProfileOutcomeIdsByStructureId(@Param("structureId") UUID structureId);
```

but it had no any effect

Comment: could you please share entity class for `ProfileInteraction`

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian added

Comment: pi ON lp.loadProfileId = pi.outcome - take a look at those mappings. One is a UUID, the other is a LoadProfile instance. You do not need the ON clause at all as you've already defined what you want in that pi.outcome mapping. Try just "FROM ProfileInteraction pi join pi.outcome lp" instead.